# Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

While converting `GridView` data to `PDF` i am getting this error. Please help me. My codes are below.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
gv.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
frm.Controls.Add(gv);
frm.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 30f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Comment: this is the code i hav used..

Comment: yes, please give us more info..

Answer (score 3):

Your html needs to be perfect or you will receive an exception.  So if you are missing a closing tag an exception is thrown

Answer (score 2):

If you have GridView in the form and its "*AllowSorting*" property is true, you should false that programatically befor *parse* and after that change it to true if you need.

Comment: This was exactly my issue as well! +1

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation while I was trying to convert a panel into PDF. The problem was that the panel had a link button, and it seems that this method Parse() just doesn't work fine with link buttons.

My solution was to make the link button invisible before the conversion and make it visible again after the conversion.

It is possible that your page contains a link button or any other controls not compatible with Parse().

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to convert this Gridview into a PDF. This Gridview had an auto-format template and a lot of columns including link buttons. Link buttons definitely causes errors when using this code.

My solution was, I created another Gridview just showing the data I needed and left it bare.(no styles at all). Make the Gridview default visibility to false. In your code behind make sure you show the Grivdiew before the data bind then hide it again once it writes to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

i think if your code is work perfectly then only one problem create with version of  itextsharp.dll,

you should vist this link and download version give in it..then after any code working perfectly,

[visit this link](http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/Export%20gridview%20to%20pdf%20in%20asp.net%20using%20c-Sharp.shrtml.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

Appears to be this problem: http://am22tech.com/s/22/Blogs/post/2011/09/28/HTML-To-PDF-using-iTextSharp.aspx